# How do I check speed of my RAM?

Tags: memory, speed

How can i know the RAM speed of my laptop?

it's an Asus K40IN-VX128

How do I make sure if the frequency is 667MHz or 800MHz, I was thinking of an upgrade.

Comment: "how do i check speed of my ram" - chase it across a field holding a stopwatch?

Comment: I've never seen a "this comment was edited" doohickey before! Ooooh comment editing happened. My mistake :3

Comment: Thanks splattne for merge, now keno can edit his question, and post comments to answers.

Answer (score 17):

Use [CPU-Z](http://www.cpuid.com/cpuz.php), assuming you're on Windows.

Comment: + 1 thats the best app to check hardware on win.

Comment: I used this CPU-Z and it clocked my RAM frequency at 398.7 Mhz.  So it didn't work for me.

Comment: What RAM do you have?

Comment: @elcool that's because it's running in dual-channel, achieving an effective 797.4 MHz (or in other words, 800 MHz - the clock frequencies are not usually exact).

Comment: @Breakthrough: It's not because of dual-channel, it's because it's DDR RAM. DDR RAM clocked at 400MHz transfers data at 800MHz. That's what DDR means -- the data rate is double the clock speed.

Answer (score 3):

The best free solution is:

1. Turn off your system.
2. Start your system.
3. Press the appropriate button for BIOS.
4. Check memory status; it gives you the speed or frequency of your RAM.

Answer (score 2):

Try with [SIW - System Information for Windows](http://www.gtopala.com/).

Maybe this one will work. (I'm still quite surprised CPU-Z didn't show memory information)

Comment: CPU-Z shows it here, on the memory and SPD tabs. DRAM frequency, channels, latency, etc.

Comment: I know it does, it does for me as well, but the OP said it wasn't working on his computer, for a reason I can't figure out.

Answer (score 1):

A list of RAM benchmarking tools is available at http://www.benchmarkhq.ru/english.html?/be_memory.html  There are a lot of freeware tools there.

Answer (score 1):

one of the easiest places ive found to get this information is

www.crucial.com/uk you can select by manufacturer / make / model etc. failing that they have a downloadable tool that will scan the PC and work it out for you.

all nice and easy. they will even recommend the best sets of ram to upgrade to and how much they can provide it for.

sorry sounds like a bit of a plug for them but hey ho there a good company that get it right!

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't give the speed.

Answer (score 1):

If you're planning on adding hardware to a machine, then it sounds like you shouldn't be afraid of a screwdriver.

Open up the flap on the bottom of the laptop and have a look at what RAM is already in there.

1) it will almost certainly have a sticker on it telling you what speed/size is currently installed.

2) It should be obvious if you have a spare ram socket (to upgrade) or whether you will have to remove what is already there and replace it with something larger.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

If you need yet another free tool, I recommend [Speccy](http://www.piriform.com/speccy), a powerful and appealing tool that shows information on your RAM and much more.

Answer (score 0):

Some Linux Live CDs like `KNOPPIX` offer to boot into memtest, which shows you RAM type, MHz and more. You can also download ISOs from http://memtest.org/